# Rename array (assign an array to a new name) in javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is pretty basic, I think.  I am a bit rusty on my javascript, though, so I may not even be looking in the right place for my problem.  I have two arrays that are quite similar.  I have an "if statement" that verifies which array to use in a "for loop".  To do this, I thought it would be easiest to assign the desired array to a new name.  Thus:

```
<body>
<div id="dataLocation">
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
oldArray1 = [["name11",51,61,"page11.html"],["name12",151,161,"page12.html"]];
oldArray2 = [["name21",61,71,"page21.html"],["name22",161,171,"page22.html"]];
function loadArray(type){
    var compiledData = "", newArray = new Array();

    if(type=="a") newArray.push(oldArray1);
    else newArray.push(oldArray2);

    for(i=0;i<newArray.length;i++){
         compiledData += "<a  href='" + newArray[i][3] + "'><img src='img.png' title='" + newArray[i][0] + "' style='position: absolute; z-index: 3; left: " + newArray[i][1]-1 + "px; top: " + newArray[i][2]-1 + "px;'></a>";
    }
    document.getElementById('dataLocation').innerHTML = compiledData;
}
window.onload = loadArray("a");
</script>
</body>
```

Currenlty the page runs with no errors in Firebug and returns the results:

> NaNpx;'>

Which appears to be from the last part of the compiledData.  It should be returning some images that are links.  When I do a console.log in firebug, it shows newArray as a string while it shows oldArray1 as an array, so I am guessing that my problem is there.

Please excuse my ignorance, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The value in newArray[i][1] is not a number. When you try to do math on it, it fails.

Comment: I edited my array a little to differentiate the text and numbers.  Aren't the numbers seen as numbers by default, or do I need to do something there?

Comment: Alert the suspected value. If it looks like a number, wrap it in parseInt() to force the type conversion.

Comment: I created a little jsfiddle of the math **[jsfiddle.net/Ty7MT/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty7MT/)** and I don't think that is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with assigning arrays

```
if(type=="a") newArray = oldArray1;
else newArray = oldArray2;
```

and also for loop, you will have to change this part  `left: " + newArray[i][1]-1 + "px; top: " + newArray[i][2]-1 + "px;'` as

```
compiledData += "<a  href='" + newArray[i][3] + "'><img src='img.png' title='" + newArray[i][0] + "' style='position: absolute; z-index: 3; left: " + newArray[i][1] + "px; top: " + newArray[i][2] + "px;'></a>";
```

**EDIT**

```
     var left_val = newArray[i][1] - 1;
     var top_val =newArray[i][2] - 1;
     compiledData += "<a  href='" + newArray[i][3] + "'><img src='img.png' title='" + newArray[i][0] + "' style='position: absolute; z-index: 3; left: " + left_val + "px; top: " + top_val + "px;'></a>";
```

Comment: Performing the math (newArray[i][1]-1) is an important part of the page.  How would you recommend I handle that?

Comment: Sweet!  I created a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htFAF/3/)** to test it out and it worked.  Both fixes were needed.  I updated it in my actual code and all the data appeared perfectly.  Thanks, Shafeeq, so awesome!